# Launching notepad using JButton and ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, bluej

I have done around 1 to 2 hours of googling for what should be a very simple question

I need to launch a txt doc, for example text.txt on my Desktop (C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\text.txt) using a button in my program GUI.

the button code is simple.

```
JButton  btnAddButton1 = new JButton("Display ShopEmployee"); // start of button
                        btnAddButton1.setVisible( false); // removing from sight
                        contentPane.add(btnAddButton1);       
                        btnAddButton.addActionListener(new creatingOpenFileListener()); // the button is going to create a Person
                        btnAddButton.setVisible(true);
```

and the action listener:

```
 class creatingOpenFileListener implements ActionListener
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
           {

           }
        }
```

I have tried everything I can, but im just out of ideas, I even traveled to page 5 of googling looking for the answer for what SHOULD be a simple question, any help would be great, thanks.

EDIT:
I do mean LAUNCH, not open up the contents in the GUI, I eman launch it as if I were to go and click on it my self.

answer

```
     try
    {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C://Users//Computer//Desktop//text.txt"));
    }
    catch(java.io.IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("IOError");
    }
```

Comment: What were you searching for? It took me about 10 seconds to find the answer on Google.

Comment: I searched "How to launch .exe using Java JButton" and many variations of that for about 2 hours, everything I tried didn't work..

Comment: 2 hrs is a lot of time to get a result on Google search unless your internet is very very slow

Comment: You could even try the `Process` class and `Runtime.exec()` method in the listener.

Comment: You should also see ***[this](http://www.howtogeek.com/106718/how-to-search-google-like-a-pro-11-tricks-you-have-to-know/)*** link about how to do **effective** searches

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like...

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:/Users/Computer/Desktop/text.txt")));
```

Take a look at [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) for more details...

Comment: Cannot find symbol class File

Comment: Did you try looking it up in the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)?  It would have lead you to `java.io.File`, which would suggest that you need to supply and `import` for it.  If you're using an IDE, this could auto correct for you...

Comment: ok so I imported it now its giving me an error that I have no idea how to deal with, this is the first time I have done anything like this. the error is "unreported exception java.i.o.IOException;Must be caught or declared to be thrown"

Comment: @user2469932 Are you trying to randomly learn the Java programming language? If so, I would suggest to read a few tutorial on the Java basics. Methods can declare that they throw exceptions and the calling code must either forward them (by declaring themselve a throw Exception clause) or catch them and handle the exception.

Comment: @user2469932 Take a look at [try-block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) for details